# PHP trying to connect to local mysql database instead of specified remote address

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, centos6

I am trying to connect to a remote MySQL database. The MySQL user has access from any IP address. I have root privileges on the Centos 6.8 VM that I am trying to connect from.

Yes I have googled this issue and so far nothing has worked. I am new to PHP so it is possible it is something simple. The path it is referring to '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' does not exist but I feel like it shouldn't be looking for this socket because the DB is not on localhost. I have also double checked that my MySQL user has permission.

My code: index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php 
   $user="myUsername";
   $password="myPW";
   $database="myDB";
   mysql_connect('xxx.x.xx.xx:xxxx',$user,$password);
   @mysql_select_db($database) or die( mysql_error());
   $query="SELECT * from myTable";
   mysql_query($query);
   mysql_close();
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

The error I get printed on the page:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

The error I get in the httpd/logs/error_log:

> [Fri Jul 08 06:26:54 2016] [error] [client xxx.x.x.xxx] PHP Warning: 
>   mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.x.xx.xx' (13)
>   in /var/www/html/index.php on line 10

Comment: Is sql safe mode enabled? http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sql.safe-mode

Comment: In [SQL safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), the host parameter is ignored.

Comment: Can you ssh into the MySQL server?  What happens when you issue the command `mysql -u username -p` this will at least tell us that you CAN indeed connect to the database ...

Comment: I can't ssh into the server but I have a connection to it with MySQL workbench on my machine.

Comment: OK .. SSH into your web server and issue `mysql -u username -p -h xhost.xhost.xhost.xhost` ?

Comment: php safe mode is off.

Comment: @Zak I was able to connect that way.

Comment: Open a page containing only `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it. In the output of the page, check MySQL extension details, specifically mysql drivers.

Comment: Also you're using mysql connect which is deprecated ..  try `mysqli`?  IE `<?php`  `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");`  `if (mysqli_connect_errno()){` `echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }` `?>`

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices

Comment: @tadman Thank you for this info. PDO has slightly better error reporting and it got me to a solution. It turns out the problem was with selinux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by disabling selinux. This was appropriate for my testing situation but for production it would probably be better to actually configure selinux to allow PHP to connect to MySQL.